# Start browser via intent, url with schema "HTTP" (uppercase) error

Tags: android, android-intent

I launch an intent using the code:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
```

Why if the url starts with "http" is valid but if url starts with "HTTP"(uppercase) it throws an ActivityNotFoundException? It's strange because the url follows the standard RFC 2396.

Comment: RFC 2396, sect. 3.1 says "Scheme names consist of a sequence of characters beginning with a
   lower case letter and followed by any combination of lower case
   letters, digits, plus ("+"), period ("."), or hyphen ("-").  For
   resiliency, programs interpreting URI should treat upper case letters
   as equivalent to lower case in scheme names (e.g., allow "HTTP" as
   well as "http")." (i.e. uppercase "HTTP" is incorrect, and although it *should* be treated equally, it does not have to).

Comment: @haraldK: You should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RFC 2396, sec. 3.1 says:

> Scheme names consist of a sequence of characters beginning with a lower case letter and followed by any combination of lower case letters, digits, plus ("+"), period ("."), or hyphen ("-"). For resiliency, programs interpreting URI should treat upper case letters as equivalent to lower case in scheme names (e.g., allow "HTTP" as well as "http").

I.e. uppercase "HTTP" is incorrect according to the spec. Although programs *should* treat uppercase as equivalent to lower case, it does not have to.

It's also trivial for you to make sure that the scheme part of your URI is in lowercase, so it's easy to avoid.

Answer (score 4):

you can use: `normalizeScheme()`

```
//Return an equivalent URI with a lowercase scheme component. 
// This aligns the Uri with Android best practices for intent filtering.
// For example, "HTTP://www.android.com" becomes "http://www.android.com" 
Uri uri =  Uri.parse(url).normalizeScheme()
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri))
```

see more here: [normalizeScheme](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri#normalizeScheme())